# PDF library tcpdf in landscape orientation and pdf->SetXY doesn't work as expected?

Tags: pdf, qr-code, tcpdf

I can not figure this one out how tcpdf recalculates x and y coordinates if orientation is landscape. The only way i can get a bit of control is to put text in a writeHTML

```
// QR code
$style = array(
    'border' => false,
    'padding' => 'auto',
    'fgcolor' => array(0,0,0),
    'bgcolor' => false
);
$pdf->SetXY(0, 0);
$pdf->write2DBarcode('http://www.google.com/', 'QRCODE,H', 0, 1, 40, 40, $style, 'N');
// set text content
$pdf->SetXY(2, 37);
//$pdf->SetXY(30, 7);
$pdf->SetFontSize(10);
$textData = '<p>Matthew Pitt</p>'
        . '<p>Google Light Company</p>';

$pdf->writeHTML($textData, true, false, false, false, 'R');
```

and the result is

[image]

Ideally I like to layout the text on the right of the QR code. Multiline if a name is very long and text-align left?? Any tips, suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For those in the same situation in my case $pdf->MultiCell did the job as I don't know how many characters a name will have. And using a table cell would not let me display a name on multiline

```
  $style = array(
    'border' => false,
    'padding' => 'auto',
    'fgcolor' => array(0, 0, 0),
    'bgcolor' => false
);
$pdf->SetXY(0, 0);
$pdf->write2DBarcode('http://www.google.com/', 'QRCODE,H', 0, 1, 40, 40, $style, 'N');
// set text content
$pdf->SetXY(42, 7);

$pdf->SetFontSize(10);
//
$textData = '<p>Matthew Pitt</p>'
        . '<p>Google Light Company</p>';
//$pdf->writeHTML($textData, true, false, false, false, 'L');
$pdf->SetXY(40, 7);
$htmlHead = '<table width="250" border="0">
              <tr>
                    <td align="left">Matthew Pitt Matthew Pitt Matthew Pitt</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                    <td align="left">Good Light Company</td>
              </tr>
            </table>';
//$pdf->writeHTML($htmlHead, true, false, true, false, '');//<- check this didn't work 100% correctly
$txt = 'Matthew Pitt Matthew Pitt Matthew Pitt Matthew Pitt Matthew Pitt Matthew Pitt';
$pdf->MultiCell(45, 5, $txt, 0, '', 0, 1, '', '', true);
$pdf->Ln(1);
$pdf->SetX(40);
$txt2 = 'Google Company Light';
$pdf->MultiCell(45, 5, $txt2, 0, '', 0, 1, '', '', true);
```

[image]